# Вывод необходимых значений полей во view

Tags: java

Есть DAO который считывает файл и преобразует данные в объект. Так же в объекте есть множество др. объектов. Нужно написать метод чтобы вытаскивать необходимые данные. Необходимо самому формировать строку для вывода ее на экран. Просто получается один объект содержит несколько др., а тот в свою очередь содержит еще др.
В итоге на выходе получается 
 [net.devsambuca.model.Developer@66048bfd, net.devsambuca.model.Developer@5474c6c]

Вот и думаю, должен быть скорее всего метод, где бы я сам формировал строку на вывод. 
А если переопределяю метод toStritg()

1, Faze Clan, 
[2, Vasya, Petr, PH Developer, [Python, Scala], 40000.0, 1, Vasya, Petrov, PHP Developer, [CSS, Java], 50000.0]

Метод read() из DAO

```
public Customer read(long id) {
        try {
            File customerFile = new File(FILE_PATH);
            Scanner customerScanner = new Scanner(customerFile);
            while (customerScanner.hasNext()) {
                Customer customer = new Customer();
                String nextLine = customerScanner.nextLine();
                String[] customerData = nextLine.split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i <customerData.length; i++) {
                    if (customerData[i].isEmpty()) continue;
                    switch (i) {
                        case 0:
                            customer.setId(Long.parseLong(customerData[i]));
                            continue;
                        case 1:
                            customer.setFirstName(customerData[i]);
                            continue;
                        case 2:
                            customer.setLastName(customerData[i]);
                            continue;
                    }
                    if (i == customerData.length - 1)
                        customer.setAdress(customerData[i]);
                    else {
                        Set<Project> projects = customer.getProjects();
                        if (projects == null) projects = new HashSet<>();
                        DaoProject daoProject = new DaoProject();
                        projects.add(daoProject.read((Long.valueOf(customerData[i]))));
                        customer.setProjects(projects);
                    }
                }
                if (id == customer.getId()) {
                    return customer;
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Так никто не помог разобрался сам.

```
private void pullOutOf(Customer customer){
        long id;
        String customerFirstName;
        id = customer.getId();
        customerFirstName = customer.getFirstName();
        System.out.println(id + "," + customerFirstName);

    }

 private void showAllCustomers() {
        List<Customer> customers = custController.getAll();
        for(Customer customer : customers)
            pullOutOf(customer);
    }
```